# Magento2 getting error on Gift cart

Tags: magento2

Getting below error when applying giftcode in shopping cart page

> *Error:*  Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: you use localhost ??

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh the page by using Ctrl+F5.
If still error exist try in different browser.

Comment: Try and let us know if its helpful and works , give upvote on the answer if it works 4 you, so it will help to others in Magento community.